# What is the best way to restrain user input to only wanted characters

Tags: python, python-2.7, input

I want user to not be able to write characters other than 'y'and 'n'
I have read from a lot of sources but none of them seems to be explaining this case.

```
ready = raw_input('\nOK, Ready? (y/n)\n')
```

Comment: `if ready.lower() in {'ok', 'y', 'yes'}:` (this also accepts `YES`, `Yes` etc).

Answer (score 0):

This is one way you can repeatedly ask for an input until the input is in a provided `set`:

```
ready = ''

while ready not in {'y', 'n'}:
    ready = raw_input('\nOK, Ready? (y/n)\n')

print('Success')
```

Note strings are case sensitive. Use `str.lower` for case insensitivity.

Also relevant: [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)